# Find conditional means for several variables by several criteria at once in R

Tags: r

There are different ways to get conditional means on several criteria for one variable. With `ave`, e.g.:

```
ave(dat$Y, dat[,c('F1','F2')], FUN=mean)
```

Or with `aggregate`, e.g.:

```
aggregate(dat$Y, list(dat$F1, dat$F2), FUN=mean)
```

Or with `group_by` and `mutate` from the `dplyr` package:

```
dat %>% group_by(F1, F2) %>% mutate(mean(Y))
```

Is there a way to do something similar but for more `Y` (response) variables at once? For example:

```
ave(dat[,c('Y1','Y2')], dat[,c('F1','F2')], FUN=mean)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` like below, for example (with `mtcars` dataset)

```
> aggregate(cbind(hp,wt)~gear+carb, mtcars, mean)
   gear carb    hp       wt
1     3    1 104.0 3.046667
2     4    1  72.5 2.072500
3     3    2 162.5 3.560000
4     4    2  79.5 2.683750
5     5    2 102.0 1.826500
6     3    3 180.0 3.860000
7     3    4 228.0 4.685800
8     4    4 116.5 3.093750
9     5    4 264.0 3.170000
10    5    6 175.0 2.770000
11    5    8 335.0 3.570000
```

where you have mean values for `hp` and `wt` columns, grouped by `gear` and `carb`